# How to append new data to the log file in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, plpgsql

I am migrating oracle code to postgresql where i need to append the query to existing log file.

Basically i want equivalent of oracle command " SPOOL test.log APPEND " in PostgreSQL . Is there a way to do that?

I tried to append new data to the log  file using \o or \o+ or copy in PostgreSQL but it overwrites the log file.

My code is something like this :

Oracle:

```
spool test.log
select  uid from users where uid='1111';
spool off

select sysdate from dual;   
//other business logic code
                                                      -
spool test.log append
select balance from balances where uid='1111';
spool off
```

Postgresql:

```
\o test.log
select  uid from users where uid='1111';
\o

select current_date;  
//other business logic code
                                                       -
\o test.log  
select balance from balances where uid='1111';
\o
```

I want the two queries in \o block to append to same file in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
\o | cat >> test.log
```

on UNIX platforms.